# python3 cannnot start after Mac upgrade from Yosemite to El Capitan

Tags: macos, python-3.x, ipython, max

I installed both **python3** and **python2.7** on my Mac, it worked well before I upgrade to `El Capitan`. After the system update, I cannot start `python3`. I type `python3` in terminal, it says:

> "-bash: python3: command not found."

But I am sure `python3` is already in my Mac, I try to use `homebrew` install it again. terminal shows that

> "Warning: python3-3.4.2_1 already installed". Here is the position:

```
boost-python    python      python3     wxpython    zpython
homebrew/apache/mod_python      homebrew/python/vpython
homebrew/versions/boost-python159   Caskroom/cask/kk7ds-python-runtime
homebrew/versions/gst-python010     Caskroom/cask/mysql-connector-python
homebrew/python/python-dbus
```

Also, `ipython` notebook also cannot start.
Anyone knows how to solve this issue? or met this problem before?

Comment: What does `which -a python3` output?

Comment: nothing, it seems that system do not recognize python3. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.